# three dots - overflow:ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My question is, why "text-overflow:ellipsis;" doesnt work for me?
I have table on my page and i want to shorten some text inside cell(td).
As you can see i have no width parameter in css. I get this value from json and then I set it with jquery. Maybe this is the problem? If so, how can i solve it?

```
#myTable2 td{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    min-width:47px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-spacing:none;
    cellpadding: 0;
    cellspacing: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

I test it in Chrome 19, newest Firefox and IE9..
Thanks

Comment: How do you expect it to shorten the text, when you don't want to place a width limit on it?

Comment: yes lanzz this is my question...as i said, i set width from json file...i get there width parameters and then i set it using jaascriopt...width depends on the user...

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you. I thought you're setting the text, not the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-overflow` works with `display: block` elements, while table cells are `display: table-cell` elements. Enclosing your text in a `<div>` [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/rAtY7/) (fiddle sets the width when you click on the text).

Answer (score 5):

You need a width of the table and table-layout:fixed;

http://jsfiddle.net/CagPK/

```
#myTable2 td{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
#myTable2 
{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100px;
}
​
```

Comment: ok i'll try with fixed layout...and as i said i set width using javascript...maybe this is the problem? :>

Comment: OK! thanks that works...i found bug in my script and fix it...now it works just fine :> ty again